# Finding Maximum of $2$ non-negative real numbers

Tags: analysis

Q) A clamp gate is an analog gate parametrized by two real numbers $a$ and $b,$ and denoted as $clamp_{a,b}.$ It takes as input two non-negative real numbers $x$ and $y.$ Its output is defined as

$clamp_{a,b}(x,y) = \left\{\begin{matrix}ax+by &\text{when}\: ax+by\geq 0,\:\text{and}  & \\ 0& \text{when}\: ax + by<0. \end{matrix}\right.$

Consider circuits composed only of clamp gates, possibly parametrized by different pairs $(a,b)$ of real numbers. How many clamp gates are needed to construct a circuit that on input non-negative reals $x$ and $y$ outputs the maximum of $x$ and $y?$

**My Attempt :** I have taken $2$ clamp gates as :
$clamp_{1,1}(x,-y) = \left\{\begin{matrix} x-y &x \geq y \\ 0 &x < y \end{matrix}\right.$    and
$clamp_{1,1}(x,y) = \left\{\begin{matrix} x+y &x+y \geq 0 \\ 0 &x+y < 0 \end{matrix}\right.$
Now, I connect the outputs of first clamp gate i.e. $x-y$ and $0$ as inputs to the $x$ parameter of $2^{nd}$ clamp gate and check the output.
For example, suppose, $x=3$ and $y=2$, Now, output of $1^{st}$ clamp gate will be $3-2$ and sends it to $x$ for $2^{nd}$ clamp gate, so $2^{nd}$ clamp gate will give output as : $3-2+2 =3$ which is the $max(3,2)$. Now if we take $x=-1$ and $y=3$, Now, output of $1^{st}$ clamp gate will be $0$ and sends it to $x$ for $2^{nd}$ clamp gate, so $2^{nd}$ clamp gate will give output as : $0+3 = 3$ which is the $max(-1,3)$.
So, $2$ clamp gates are sufficient to find maximum of $2$ non-negative real numbers

Is my approach correct ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let me use $c$ for the clamp.

Note that $c_{1,0}(x,y) = \max(0,x)$ and $c_{0,1}(x,y) = \max(0,y)$.

Note that $c_{1,1}(x,y) = \max(0,x+y)$.

Hence $c_{1,1}(c_{1,0}(x,y), c_{0,1}(x,y)) = \max(0,\max(0,x)+\max(0,y))$.

Comment: Thank you. It is taking 3 clamp gates. We can do it with 2 gates. Right ? And I think, In last line, it should be $c_{1,1}(c_{1,0}(x,y), c_{0,1}(x,y)) = \max(0,\max(0,x)+\max(0,y)). $@copper.hat, can you please tell me whether my approach is correct or not ?

Comment: Can you write your solution as a composition as above? I don't follow what you are doing.

Comment: would $clamp_{1,1}(clamp_{1,1}(x,-y),y)$ work ?

Comment: How do you generate $-y$?

Comment: Yes, Thanks. I did mistake. So, we need atleast 3 gates here. Right ?

Comment: $-y$ can be generated by $clamp_{0,-1}(x,y) $. So, I am also getting 3 gates here. Let me try again whether we can get max(x,y) using 2 gates or not. Thank you for the answer @copper.hat

Comment: I was adding that as a comment when you deleted the question :-). You may be able to do two gates, I just don't see it now. If you write the formula it is easy to check...

Comment: No need to accept the answer if it doesn't help you.

Comment: yes, sorry. @copper.hat :( I accepted the answer because you put your time and I will get back to you later after trying for 2 gates :)

Comment: Actually, I have used only 1 gate in my previous comment. So, If I add $clamp_{0,-1}(x,y)$, then 2 gates will be there. So, according to me, $clamp_{1,1}(clamp_{1,1}(x,clamp_{0,-1}(x,y)),y)) = max(x,y)$. Can you please check whether it is correct or not @copper.hat

Comment: One of the clamps has 3 parameters.

Comment: now, it is corrected.

Comment: Unfortunately not, as far as I can tell, if $x=y=2$ then your formula gives $4$.

Comment: yeah, it is also not working when $x=2$ and $y=3$. Anyway, I can proceed further from here. Thanks for the response.